# Flask sqlalchemy how to display model query results as html table

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to generate an html table where the header row and data rows are a subset of fields returned by a sqlalchemy model query. I can't find any examples of this but feel it must be a common requirement.

The following is my query where Route is defined as an sqlalchemy model:

```
data = Route.query.filter_by(fid=fid).all()
```

I want to display the results of this query as an html table in my template but only after excluding certain fields and adjusting values of other fields before displaying. The all() query appears to return a list of objects but I need to exclude certain fields/columns in each object.

For example I don't want to display the fid column in my table and I want the name column to be displayed as a hyperlink. My specific questions are:

1. How do I iterate through the column headings for my data and display these as an html table but excluding certain columns that were returned by the query?
2. How do I iterate through the corresponding data rows and columns and display them in the html table?

I know how to generate a table in the template but not how to iterate through the columns and rows returned by the query. Any help greatly appreciated as this has been perplexing me for days now.

Comment: I will suggest using Pandas.You than easily integrate sqlalchemy query into pandas DataFrame.

Comment: `df = pd.read_sql(sql = db.session.query(Route).with_entities(Route.field1,
                                        Route.field2,
                                        Route.field3).statement, 
                 con = db.session.bind)`

Comment: After all you can print table to html using pandas `DataFrame.to_html`

Comment: Thank you I'll have a further look at pandas - maybe source code will show how to do it? I'm keen to understand how this conversion works and replicate myself as trying to learn flask/python logic.

Comment: Does answer that I provided satisfies you?

Comment: In part. Is there an option that doesn't use pandas? Also  how would I exclude a certain column eg fid across multiple models with differing columns?